# how to slow down one method without affecting the rest of the program?

Tags: java, random

I'm making a game in Java and I want to create a character that moves randomly. The one I made is very spastic. I basically want to add a delay between random numbers generated. I'm a beginner so don't judge my code lol

```
public class Monster extends Entity{

private World world;

Image monster;

public Monster(int x, int y, World world) {
        super(x, y, world);
        w = 32;
        h = 32;
        this.world = world;
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException{
        super.render(gc, g);
        monster = new Image("gfx/world/monster.png");
        g.drawImage(monster, x, y);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException{
    super.update(gc, delta);
    Random move = new Random();
    int number;

    for(int counter=1; counter<=1;counter++){
        number = move.nextInt(4); 
        System.out.println(number);


        if(number == 0){
            setDy(-1);
        }else if(number == 1){
            setDx(-1);
        }else if(number == 2){
            setDy(5);   
        }else if(number == 3){
            setDx(5);
        }else{
            setDx(0);
            setDy(0);

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what calls your update function. it looks like you want to slow down what ever is calling that, not the update itself

Answer (score 1):

This is a common technique used on games to have a different update and render rate.
What you have to do is (examples in pseudo code):

1 - Initialize a time variable - DateTime lastUpdate = new DateTime();

Every time you enter in the loop:

2 - Check if a certain time has passed - lastUpdate.hasPassed(X_TIME, new DateTime());

3 - if the time has passed (last line was true) lastUpdate = new DateTime();

4 - Else return

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
 try {
      Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where `ms` - how many miliseconds, e.g. 1000

Comment: Wherever you want, for example, inside your method update. See code update above as well.

Comment: The problem about this solution (inserting a sleep on the current thread) is that all the program will sleep when you could be computing other stuff/rendering.

Comment: @NunoPinheiro `Thread#sleep` only delays execution of the *current thread*, not the all threads handled by the program.

Comment: @Vulcan, that is true. What I meant is that in this scenario he is probably running only one thread in a single threaded game engine/framework which calls its code. So in this scenario, I believe the whole program would sleep.

Comment: A good idea if you're implementing threads- however, this looks like a practice run at writing a basic game, and threads would probably overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to encapsulate the NPC movement in a separate thread, and within that thread call thread.sleep to pause the movement.

Here is a good tutorial on [how to define threads](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-implement-thread-in-java.html), and the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) show an example of a thread that sleeps.